# Creating a 3D map for XNA?

Tags: 3d, xna, c#, maps

Is anyone aware of a nice 3D map tutorial (how to import and use the map) using XNA without any engine but not limited to an external application (like Tiled for 2D maps) ?

I did a search arund here but have'nt found anything towards xna 3d maps only 2d.

PS: **I am looking for material that can be read online with no cost if possible.**

**I would be very interested in knowing any other contents related to this subject other then what  Ricket contributed.**

Best regards.

Comment: There are a few XNA samples that deal with heightmap terrain as well: http://creators.xna.com/en-GB/sample/generatedgeometry

Comment: @DrDeth thanks but I am not using the 4.0 just yet would that example be easy to convert to 3.1 or it would be complicated considering the changes from 3.1 to 4.0 ?

Comment: I think the concepts are pretty generic and this particular example was around long before 4.0, so I think it should be quite straightforward to get it working.

Comment: @DrDeth i see, thanks i will take a look at it once i finish playing around with the 2D stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to search for tutorials on "terrain", which is the technical term for a 3D map. Also "heightmap" might return results.

Here is one possibility (notice the "Contents" section on the right bottomish): http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php

---

Due to the comment that you're looking for online content which can be read: This IS an online tutorial! It can indeed be read online! When you go to the above link, **look on the right side, the third section is "Contents"; in that box, look for the links under "3D Series 1: Terrain".**

For example, here is one very relevant section: ["Terrain from file"](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php)

Comment: Please read my edit. You must not have noticed it but this is indeed a tutorial!

Comment: That's correct i am sorry i was in rush when i replied and just gave it a look and didnt noticed the right side menu i was thinking it would be something in the body of the page but there wasnt anything and at the left side all i saw was the book etc, which made me come too fast to a conclusion, thanks for the update and to the upvotes i can now reward you aswell :)