# XNA 3d Terrain using rectangular elements

Tags: xna, 3d, terrain-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a 3D map for XNA ?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/creating-a-3d-map-for-xna)

I am developing using XNA, a simple 3d tower defense game. I wanted create a 3d terrain. 
Here is how I am doing it:

1. fundamental element is a texture of grass, overlaid on a --> rectangle / cube ...( not sure about this)
2. These elements are much smaller than the entire game screen. Some equi-spaced elements are filled on the game screen with some randomly generated z values.
3. others need to interpolate between the z values.

Now the question is how to :

Actually implement it. method 1 is to have each element be completely straight, with normal in y direction, and vary z gradually. method 2 is have the rectangle/ cube surface tilt. 
If I do method 1 it might look pretty shabby. using method 2, I don't know how to get the surface z value at all the points, on the eventual terrain, which moving enemies will walk on / towers will be placed on.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thnx.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/creating-a-3d-map-for-xna

Comment: I think you may be approaching this problem incorrectly, the link I posted should give you some helpful information on how to create 3d maps for use in XNA.

Comment: thnx... that helps